# Is there a symbol for a repeated logical and operation?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

For example, given a predicate $P$ and a set of variables: $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,...\}$, is there a single symbol similar to $\sum_{k=1}^n$ or $\bigcap_{k=1}^n$ to denote the following?

$$P(x_1)\land{P}(x_2)\land{P}(x_3)\land{P}(x_4)\land\dots$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [bounded quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier). The most common notation for what you wish to do is

$$\bigwedge_{k=1}^n P(x_k)$$

produced by `\bigwedge_{k=1}^{n} P(x_k)`, but I've also seen

$$\forall k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}.\ P(x_k).$$

For $\lor$ there is $\bigvee_{k=1}^{n}$ produced by `\bigvee_{k=1}^{n}`.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Or you can write `\bigvee_{k=1}^n`.  The braces around the "n" are necessary only when there's more than one character there, as in `\bigvee_{k=1}^{n+1}`.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeah, my $P(x_k)$ is `P(x_k)` not `P(x_{k})`, on the other hand, my experience is that with all kinds of sums/unions/etc. 1) braces help to separate the superscript from the rest of the formula; 2) the top may change and adding/removing the braces all the time would be cumbersome; 3) whenever it's $n$ or $n-1$, it all looks the same and it's easier for some regexp editions (like changing all $n$-s to $m$-s or adding floor markers $\lfloor \ldots \rfloor$).

Comment: The question was not about TeX specifics anyway.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It wasn't, but even the OP's first post on math.se was done with LaTeX (or so the history shows), thus I've guessed that the appropriate commands for might be handy (for the OP or whoever else visits this page later).